# Getting Job Downtime in a Logfile if it has a duplicate

Tags: bash, shell, unix, batch-processing

I'm trying to figure out how to determine the corresponding restart time (the last restart before job finally completed) of a specific job that abended (abnormal termination).

For example:

- Job ABC ran at 5:00
- Job ABC abended at 5:03
- It was restarted at 5:05
- Job ABC abended again at 5:08
- It was restarted again at 5:10
- Job ABC completed at 5:15

In this example, I can safely assume that the completion time of Job ABC which first ran at 5:00 is 5:15. I’m trying to compute the downtime of Job ABC  by subtracting the time it was last restarted from the first time it abended ( 5:10 – 5:03 = 7mins downtime).

This is what I did to get the first failure and the last restart time:

```
grep abended logfile | head -1   #first failure
grep restarted logfile | tail -1 #last restart
```

But the problem is what if another Job ABC runs at 6:00?

Let say,

- Another Job ABC ran at 6:00.
- It abended at 6:03.
- It was restarted at 6:05
- Job ABC completed at 6:07.

I can no longer use the head and tail I stated above if this is the case.

How can I tell if the restart at 6:05 corresponds to another Job ABC which first abended at 6:03?

By the way, I’m trying to create an automated tool that will get the downtime of a job and my only reference is a plain text log file which is auto created every 24hours.

NOTE: I'm using Bash script.

Comment: it's better if you post a sample file and a sample output. Looks like this is an `awk` job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cat tmp.log

```
Job ABC ran at 5:00

Job ABC abended at 5:03

It was restarted at 5:05

Job ABC abended again at 5:08

I was restarted again at 5:10

Job ABC completed at 5:15

Another Job ABC ran at 6:00.

It abended at 6:03.

It was restarted at 6:05

Job ABC completed at 6:07.
```

---

```
 awk '{if(s==0 && /abended/){s = 1;st = $NF}}{if(s && /restarted/) {et = $NF}}1; /completed/{s=0;print "Downtime of this job was: "et "-" st}' tmp.log
```

This would give the following output :

```
Job ABC ran at 5:00

Job ABC abended at 5:03

It was restarted at 5:05

Job ABC abended again at 5:08

I was restarted again at 5:10

Job ABC completed at 5:15
Downtime of this job was: 5:10-5:03

Another Job ABC ran at 6:00.

It abended at 6:03.

It was restarted at 6:05

Job ABC completed at 6:07.
Downtime of this job was: 6:05-6:03.
```